# Is there a way to smooth out face landmarks from face_recognition? Maybe via PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to make an eye-replacement program that can fill eyes with an image. For finding the eyes, I am using face_recognition by Ageitgey. However, the eye detection comes out very jagged.

(I'm not talking about anti-aliasing, btw. I'll use super-sampling to solve that later)

Here's my tiny bit of code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import face_recognition

image = face_recognition.load_image_file("media/test_input_image.jpg")

face_landmark_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)

for face_landmarks in face_landmark_list:
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(image)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image, 'RGBA')

    d.polygon(face_landmarks["right_eye"], fill=(255, 0, 0, 255))

    pil_image.show()
```

**example:** [Daniel's surprisingly terrifying badly selected eyes]

[image]

I want it looking more smooth. I am looking to achieve something like the green eye on the left, but am currently getting the red eye on the right. (The green eye was drawn on with Gimp.)

So, basically, is there a way to go from the red result, to the green?

Comment: Look like you want to fit the polygon with the intersection of a pair of circles. I have no idea how to do that but it seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: This would be fitting the eye with a lens. A lens being the term for the shape formed by the intersection of two circles

Comment: @DanD. Yeah, that's a way to explain it! What I was thinking was smoothing out the connections to the bottom two points and the top two points, but doing something like that might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1: (Easy)**

- Use quadratic or cubic regression to fit a curve using left/right and 2 upper points
- Do the same thing for left/right and 2 lower points.
- Sampling depends on how many points you want for each.
  [image]

Sample python code:

```
import numpy.polynomial.polynomial as poly
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Grab x, y coordinates from eyes in face_recognition result
# Here is the example point.
x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5])
y = np.array([1, 1.5, 1.5, 1])

# x_new: upsampling 40 points from x
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num=len(x)*10)

coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 3)
y_new = poly.polyval(x_new, coefs)

plt.plot(x_new, y_new,'r-')
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.show()
```

**Method 2: (Difficult)**

- Use dlib, re-train object detector to just detect eyes with more than 6 points, e.g. 64 points for just one eye, you'll get smoother result.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Could you explain what `x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num=len(x)*10)` does in a little more detail?

Comment: You're welcome! `x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num=len(x)*10)` creates a new array of evenly spaced numbers (40 points) from the first item to the last item of x array.

Comment: Ah, I see.
Does the order of the coordinates matter, as long as they match between the separate x and y lists?
If we name the points from left to right, A to D, would it matter if they were listed as [B, C, D, A] before we do the regression?
Or using your example, listing it as:
`x = np.array([5, 1, 2, 4])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1.5, 1.5])`

Comment: It doesn't affect regression result, but take care the x_new (run linspace from A->D)